# "Fishing job" - can't complete

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've got a fishing job from the thieves guild and it takes place in Markarth. The individual that I'm supposed to steal from is named Imedhnain, and he is located in Arnleif and Sons Trading Company. I have been unable to find him anywhere else but there, although he may leave at certain times of the day - I'm not sure. In any case, when I break in to Arnleif and Sons at night, as soon as I break in I am seen by him and Lisbet, as they're having a conversation at a counter directly in front of me. I've tried breaking in at different hours of the night, but every time they're there at the counter. Also, I've tried using an invisibility potion before lockpicking the door, but the potion seems to expire right when I enter.

How exactly do I go about stealing from this fool if I get caught every time I break-in?

Comment: Is the building he's in locked during the day as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Apparently there is a bug where Arnleif and Sons is locked all of the time. However, picking the lock once will fix the problem and the store will open as it should during the normal day hours. I found a reference to this bug [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arnleif_and_Sons_Trading_Company)

Comment: usually, doors still say they are locked during the day but may not be (but they don't update since you may have been staring at it during the transition).  In this particular case, its a bug but for other doors, it helps if you look away from the door before waiting for some time.

Comment: Ah, didn't think to check if you had Dawnguard.

Comment: That's just it - I don't. I know that article I linked to said it's just a Dawnguard bug, but I saw it even without the expansion!

Answer (score 0):

Fishing jobs are completed when you successfully steal the target item.  You shouldn't be required to break in to complete it.  Enter the building during the day, drink your invis potion after breaking in so you can successfully pickpocket him.

Comment: It's locked during the day also. Forgot to mention that part of it. And it doesn't give me time to drink a potion when I enter, because Lisbet is looking straight at me.

Answer (score -2):

This is my process for completing it:
For helgird.
0% pickpocket.
Sneak 98. Pickpocket 34. Enchanted ring. Pickpocket 40% necklace same.
Enchanted a pickaxe with paralysis.
When she was at grave casting spell, I snuck up and hit her while staying hidden.
As she rises I activated pickpocket, got it.
Moved away till hidden again.
Quest Completed.